# What does [W_Wad] mean?

Tags: symbols, continued-fractions

Found this one in closed forms of a fraction.

Wolfram only gives a way to copy as plain text:

```
(3830 W_Wad)/1177≈0.97621070518266779949
```

And then it won't recognise it in other queries.
[image]

The same way with other one.

[image]

This time it is Hausdorff space, however still can't be used.
And I want to try to represent other fractions with them.

```
1/538 (1782 T_2 + 29)≈0.96127984536688108141
```

Comment: Just a fraction, as stated. 0.96127984536688108141

Comment: `W_Wad` looks like LaTeX. Where did you get it? In *Mathematica* it means any expression with `Wad` as its `Head`, bound to the name `W` for use in a definition or replacement rule. That's not how you're using it here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you say "Wolfram" I am guessing that you mean Wolfram|Alpha. This site is for Q&A concerning Mathematica and the Wolfram Language. Questions solely about Wolfram|Alpha are off-topic. If you are using Mathematica then start with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Whatever the source, `W_Wad` has the value `3/10` and `T_2` has the value `0.27394419573927161717`